# Trouble connecting to the database from Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm working on a Zend project and I have trouble with connecting to the database.

Here is my application.ini

```html
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "ZendExtended"
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Jnm"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/"
resources.modules[] = ""

resources.session.cookie_lifetime = 0


logs.configFile = APPLICATION_PATH "/configs/logs.ini"

resources.view[] =

javascriptPath = "js/"
cssPath = "css/"


resources.db.adapter = "Mysqli"
resources.db.params.host = "jnmfrtgeanbdddev.mysql.db"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "pass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "bdd"
resources.db.params.port = "3306"

register.validation = 1
register.available = 1


[preprod : production]
database.params.dbname = "database-preprod-jnm"
database.params.username = "user-preprod-mysql"

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

database.adapter = "Mysqli"
database.params.host = "127.0.0.1"
database.params.dbname = "database-test-jnm"
database.params.username = "root"
database.params.password = ""

register.validation = 1
register.available = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

database.adapter = "Mysqli"
database.params.host = "jnmfrtgeanbdddev.mysql.db"
database.params.dbname = "bdd"
database.params.username = "user"
database.params.password = "pass"

register.validation = 1
register.available = 1

[development2 : development]

database.adapter = "Mysqli"
database.params.host = "127.0.0.1"
database.params.dbname = "database-dev-jnm"
database.params.username = "root"
database.params.password = ""
```

Here is Environment that I call in my index.php. I chose the `production` environment:

> define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?
>   getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

The website works, but still isn't connected to the database. What could be the problem here?

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Also, have you got any env setup in the .htaccess or on your machine somewhere? (chances are you're not really on production)